# transactions with spring 3 / jdbctemplate and postgresql 9.3

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

I tried to enable transactions in my app and something is not going OK.

app context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/db"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" >
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

</beans>
```

service class sample:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ProviderManager {

    @Autowired private ProviderDao providerDao;
    @Autowired private ProvisionDao provisionDao;
```

(...)

```
public void save(BindingResult result, Provider provider){

        try{
            check(result,provider);
            if(!result.hasErrors()){
                        providerDao.save(provider);
                        provisionDao.saveProvider(provider);
            }

        }catch(org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException e){
            result.addError(new ObjectError("page", "Error!"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            result.addError(new ObjectError("page","Error: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e) ));
        }

    }
```

dao class sample:

```
@Repository
public class ProvisionDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


public void save(Provider provider){

        Timestamp now = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        if(provider.getId() == null){

            provider.setId(incrementer.nextLongValue());

            String query  = "insert into " + TABLE + " (" + COLUMNS + ") values (?)";

            this.jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[]{ provider.getId() });


        }else{

            provider.setModificationDate(now);


            String query = "update " + TABLE + " set " +
                    " MODIFICATION_DATE=?" +
                    " WHERE ID=?" ;
            this.jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[]{
                    provider.getModificationDate(),
                    provider.getId()
            });

        }

    }
```

```
@Repository
public class ProvisionDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void save(Provision provision){

        Timestamp now = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        if(provision.getId() == null){

            provision.setId(incrementer.nextLongValue());

            String query  = "insert into " + TABLE + " (" + COLUMNS + ") values (?,?)";

            this.jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[]{
                    provision.getId(),
                    provision.getProviderId()
                });


        }else{

            provision.setModificationDate(now);

            String query = "update " + TABLE + " set " +
                    " MODIFICATION_DATE=?" +
                    " WHERE ID=?" ;
            this.jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[]{
                    provision.getModificationDate(),
                    provision.getId()
            });

        }

    }
```

when `defaultAutocommit` is set to false I got:

Err: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into dict_provisions (id, creation_date, creation_user, modification_date, modification_user, status, provider_id, name, quantity) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]; foreign key in dict_providers does not exists.

so session doesn't see first save action, when `defaultAutocommit` is set to `true`, even if in second method is thrown exception first save is not rolled back. Another test I did: nothing is saved when this param is set to false.

Anybody got same problem? I will be gratefull for any tip.

Comment: Can you paste the code from both the DAO methods?

Comment: You posted your app context but nowhere in that config is a service declared. If that is loaded in a different context nothing is going to be transactional. Next to that your service method is flawed as you should never catch and swallow the exception. This breaks proper tx management.

Comment: i did copy/paste of simplified version both methods. Is that enough?

Comment: @M.Deinum : that's the point! I had root-contex and applicationContext, sessions and db settings were in first one, and scanning for services was in app-contex, now it's in one xml file and works great! thanks a lot for your help!